# Analysis of simple RC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, transient

[image]

For the above circuit,

Natural response will be *A×exp (-t/RC)* where A is any constant.

For forced response, capacitor is open circuited consequently, 10K resistor is also removed and thus, forced response is 10Cos (2t).

Plugging into the eq. For V (t) and solving at t=0 I get A=-5. But still I am not getting the answer printed in the image. HELP NEEDED!

THANK YOU

Comment: Can you provide more steps please? Do you need to solve it using differential equations, or via the Laplace transform? Have you already found the KCL laws?

Comment: @SvenB using differential eq.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the KCL equations you found?

Comment: @SvenB I did it with thevenin equivalent.

Comment: Why do you think that the 10k and the capacitor can be ignored when calculating the forced response?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: @DaveTweed Because as t tends to be very large capacitor will be open circuited. So no current will flow across 10K resistor

Comment: That only applies to the DC response. Your forcing function is AC.

Comment: @DaveTweed then how should I tackle it?

Comment: You've already accepted an answer. If that didn't meet your needs, you shouldn't have done that.

Comment: @DaveTweed That answer serves what  the purpose for what I posted here. The particular question you have raised I need answer to that. Please provide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments I'm assuming you already found the differential equation to solve, so I'll start from there:

\$v_C + \frac{1}{2}\frac{dv_C}{dt} = 10 \cos(2t)\$

**Finding the homogeneous solutions**

\$v_C + \frac{1}{2}\frac{dv_C}{dt} = 0\$

We can find from \$1 + \frac{1}{2}\lambda = 0\$ that \$\lambda = -2\$. Our homogeneous solution will therefore be:

\$v_{C,h} = A\cdot e^{-2t}\$

**Finding the particular solution**

\$v_C + \frac{1}{2}\frac{dv_C}{dt} = f(t)\$ where \$f(t) = 10 \cos(2t)\$

We therefore try a particular solution of

\$v_{C,p} = B \cos(kt) + C \sin(kt) + D\$

\$\frac{dv_{C,p}}{dt} = -Bk \sin(kt) + Ck \cos(kt)\$

Now we need to find out \$B, C\$ and \$D\$.

\$\left(B\cos(kt) + C\sin(kt) + D\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(-Bk\sin(kt) + Ck\cos(kt)\right)=10\cos(2t)\$

We find that \$k = 2\$, \$B + C = 10\$, \$B - C = 0\$ and \$D = 0\$. This gives us simply:
\$k = 2, B = C = 5, D = 0\$.

**Finding the total solution**

The total solution is the sum of the homogeneous and the particular solution. We also still need to match the initial conditions. We find that

\$v_C = v_{C,h} + v_{C,p} = Ae^{-2t} + 5\cos(2t) + 5\sin(2t)\$

To find \$A\$ we can plug in our initial condition for \$v_C\$:

\$v_C(t=0) = A + 5 = 0 \Rightarrow A = -5\$.

So the final solution is

\$v_C = -5e^{-2t} + 5\cos(2t) + 5\sin(2t)\$

Comment: Thank You very much. All I was missing was : Solution of differential equations when RHS is Sin/Cosine is of the form A×Sint + B×Cost.